# Group by apply to multiple columns?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, data-science

I have a df below as:

```
Name | Factory | Restaurant | Store | Building
Brian    True    False        True     False
Mike     True    True         True     True
Brian    True    False        False    True
Sam      False   False        False    False
Sam      True    False        True     True
Mike     True    False        False    False
```

I have code below that gives me the number of times a column like Factory is True for each name, how can I add the rest or more columns to have all the values that are true for each column like Restaurant and Store and Building and more columns too? Thanks!

```
df.groupby(['Name'])['Factory'].apply(sum).reset_index()
```

Current output:

```
Name | Factory
Brian    2
Mike     2
Sam      1
```

Expected output:

```
Name | Factory | Restaurant | Store | Building
Brian    2          0           1        1
Mike     2          1           1        1
Sam      1          0           1        1
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A couple of advise: 1) try not to use `apply`, 2) `sum` is non-vectorized Python operation, try avoid that in favor for Pandas' `'sum'` operator.

Just try:

```
cols = ['Factory', 'Restaurant', 'Store', 'Building']

df.groupby('Name', as_index=False)[cols].sum()
```

Output:

```
    Name  Factory  Restaurant  Store  Building
0  Brian        2           0      1         1
1   Mike        2           1      1         1
2    Sam        1           0      1         1
```

Comment: There are other columns in the df is there any way I can only select the ones I want ?

Answer (score 0):

When you have `df.groupby(['Name'])['Factory']` it's only going to return the Factory column

Assuming `Name` is not your index try:

`df.groupby('Name').sum().astype('int')`